# Who makes this 5-pin connector?

Tags: identification, connector

There are NO identifying marks on this plug or it's mating jack.
The body is 8mm dia if you include the key.
It has two keys - may be type "C" polarization.
The shell is 15mm dia and screws down to the mating jack.
Used on a Stalker PRO II Speed Sensor.[image]

Comment: Yikes, that's a toughie. If you check out the sensor's user manual, page 13, there's a mechanical drawing of the connector from head on. And if you search for "stalker antenna cable" you'll find full cables for sale, but that doesn't really help with the connector ID. Good luck!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a semi-custom connector and it's proprietary to Stalker. I checked eBay and found a few new / original part number cables and will just modify one of those for my use. BTW - the drawing of the connector is on page 8 of my Pro 2 Speed Sensor manual. Thanks for your help - much appreciated!